# ReactJS => local image not loading

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using ReactJS for this project, everything runs fine except the images.

What's weird is that it loads external images, like "http://Example.com/image.jpg" but it doesn't load the local image

```
<img src={'/imgs/logo.jpg'} />
```

Please help me?

thank you!

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <nav className="navbar" role="navigation">
            <div className="navbar-header">
                <Link to="/App">
                    <img src={'/imgs/logo.png'} alt="Jybly Logo" />
                </Link>
              <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <img className="bar" src='/imgs/icon-bar.png' />
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
              {/*
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Stay</a></li>
              </ul> */}
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><Link to="/pages/register">Login/Join</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/pages/cart">Cart</Link></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            {/*/.nav-collapse */}
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Do you use webpack? If yes, you have to import image first like import imageName from './imgs/logo.png'; and then <img src={imageName} />

Answer (score 2):

You need to `const image = require('imgs/logo.png')` the image as mentioned by @Louie4 and @hinok. Then you can use it in your code `<img src={ image } />`. Also,you need to include the file loader as follows (code for `webpack2`):

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...,
      { test: /\.png$|\.jpg$/, loader: 'file-loader' }, // Add other extensions if needed
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try requiring in your img src, like this:

```
<img src={ require('/imgs/logo.png') }/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

It was as simple as this,

I was coding it like this:

```
img src={ require('/imgs/logo.png') }/>
```

or like this:

```
img src={'/imgs/logo.png'}/>
```

But it's actually like this:

```
img src={ require('../imgs/logo.png') }/>
```

2 dots, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this :

```
import logo from '/imgs/logo.png'
```

and use it like this :

```
 <img src={logo} alt="Jybly Logo" />
```